# Broken bootstrap in production on Rails 4/ubuntu

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

We fixed broken bootstrap on production server (ubuntu) before. But this time the problem is sticky.

Here is our `config/environment/production.rb`

```
config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present? #false

  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier

  config.assets.compile = true 

  config.assets.digest = true
```

Here is a list of files in `assets/stylesheet`:

[image]

Here is `assets/javascripts`:

[image]

The Rails 4 production deployment used to work fine before this deployment. This time however after deployment, we did as usual:

```
  RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

But bootstrap is broken. The CSS is completely off on home page and `bootstrap carousal` does not work any more.

In `config/environment/production.rb`, we added:

```
config.assets.precompile =  ['*.js', '*.scss', '*.css', '*.css.erb']
```

But this change renders page completely no show with error ($main-bk-color not defined. The var is defined in user_menus.css.scss as #FFF). What else we can try to fix the broken bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to want to import your css files in application.css.scss and not depend on the precompile. Example:

```
# app/assets/stylesheets/applicaiton.css.scss
@import "./bootstrap-theme.css.scss";
@import "./user_menus.css.scss"
...
```

That way your files have access to the SASS variables everywhere and not just in the file they are being created.

Comment: The problem found is missing bootstrap.min.css. Your post reminds me checking the files under staylesheet..